# VSCode GDB freeze at start

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, gdb, freeze

when running VSCode and trying to debug thanks to gdb configured, it shows this in the debug section but nothing happens, it is frozen ... 
Would someone know about this problem ?

```
=thread-group-added,id="i1"
GNU gdb (GDB) 9.1
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin19.3.0".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
=cmd-param-changed,param="startup-with-shell",value="off"
Warning: Debuggee TargetArchitecture not detected, assuming x86_64.
=cmd-param-changed,param="pagination",value="off"
[New Thread 0x1003 of process 1306]
```

Comment: Probably one of these issues: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2438 or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/3829.

Comment: sorry but none of them work ...

Comment: the binary doesn't even start running

Comment: Have you tried lldb rather than gdb?

Comment: No, I was trying to make this work for now 3 hours but I think that I have to move on, I'm exhausted!

Comment: It works now thanks ! I just can't have the terminal into VSCode even with the command set to true ...